# iOS default region span for tracking

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, location

I am setting up a map view centered with the device current location. Wonder what's the default (or conventional) span size for showing this kind of view? Specifically

```
region.center.latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
region.center.longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
region.span.latitudeDelta = ?
region.span.longitudeDelta = ?
```

Is there some default values that the iOS map app uses? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what the default is, if any, but you may have an easier time using MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance which lets you specify meters and the sdk will calculate the span for you.

Comment: Thanks, Anna! I still need to have my own latitudinalMeters and longitudinalMeters in order to use MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance. But i will try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The default span I'm pretty sure is equal to 0.05.
So for instance:

float spanX = 0.05f;
float spanY = 0.05f;